# How secure Shared Preferences data in my application from Security Auditor

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

How to secure `SharedPreferences` data in my application?.

I use 2 step for this but in Security Audit hacker are able to hack my data.

1 Step-

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();           
editor.putString("key", value);
editor.commit();
```

2 Step- Use SecureSharePreferences

```
SecurePreferences securePrefs = new SecurePreferences(context, "key", "my_user_prefs.xml");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =securePrefs.edit();
editor.putString(key, value);
editor.commit();
```

Any other method to handle this.

After read some Answer I update my code with encrypt data but problem still exist.Security auditor still getting application sharedpreference.file from app memory.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String keyEncript = EncriptionDecriptionUtils.encriptionOfData(key).toString().trim().replaceAll("\r\n", "");
        String value = sharedPreferences.getString(keyEncript, "").trim().replaceAll("\r\n", "");
        String valuedecript = EncriptionDecriptionUtils.decriptionOfData(value).toString().trim().replaceAll("\r\n", "");
        return valuedecript;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt & decrypt the shared preferences data using AES algorithm.If you open shared preferences explicitly you will get encrypted information only.For your reference look into this [Securing SharedPreferences Data using AES algorithm](http://www.tutorialsface.com/2015/09/android-secure-encrypted-sharedpreferences-example-tutorial/)

Comment: My target to secure all shared preference file from hacking.

Answer (score 0):

On a rooted phone, it can access the shared preferences for your app. Also, on any phone the user can delete all the data that it's stored in shared preferences by clearing the cache in the application manager. A safe way to store data would be to encrypted it with **AES** and save it in a text file in the root folder of your app.

Comment: My target to secure all shared preference file from hacking.